# Cannot mount Windows partition in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, gnome-disk-utility

I have a dual-boot (Win10-Ubuntu 18) for more than 6 months and everything went fine.

Today I decided to give more space to my Ubuntu system (35GB -> 80GB). I resized my Windows partition and used Gparted from a live USB to move and resize the Ubuntu partition.

Everything works fine except that I cannot mount the Windows NTFS partition in Ubuntu. It used to mount at startup but now it does not work anymore.

When I try to mount it from *gnome-disks*, I have the following error message:

> **Error mounting filesystem**
>
> Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
>   (g-dbus-error-quark, 4)

My mount options for startup:

[image: Mount options from gnome-disks]

Output to `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="d4a3793e-c4fb-4c37-935f-5d93dea784a9" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="B00C-C059" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI" PARTUUID="aa0b5433-ec02-4dec-b7d3-bf1a7bf709dd"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Micr" PARTUUID="5a178315-4643-4f4f-b83b-f3da3dc3e516"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="OS" UUID="01D5F7A77E62A210" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e9608550-2e92-4869-8b73-6d0d04883a61"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="d03c5ca4-6136-48c2-887a-738ed594bf37" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a3f29106-3620-4d23-979c-ba8fa05d2515"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="EE58B72A58B6F087" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basi" PARTUUID="432fa279-29d2-47e7-aef8-f0713cb47027"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop25: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop26: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop27: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop28: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop29: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop30: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop31: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Content of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
#UUID=B00C-C059  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/E26A0E916A0E6321 /mnt/os auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=B00C-C059  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1

# /dev/nvme0n1p3

#/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D5F7A77E62A210 /mnt/os auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
#UUID=01D5F7A77E62A210 /mnt/os auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
#UUID=01D5F7A77E62A210
UUID=01D5F7A77E62A210 /mnt/os auto noatime,user,nls=utf8,windows_names,dmask=022,fmask=111,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

When I try to mound by command line, nothing happens.

In Windows, fast boot and hibernate are disabled. I always shut down properly before opening Ubuntu.

This is an important issue for me as I work in my Windows Documents from Ubuntu.

I hope somebody will help me out! Thanks!

---

**Edit:**

I found out I can mount it correctly using *gparted*. Moreover, There are size differences between *gparted* and *gnome-disks*, as if *gnome-disks* wasn't able to refresh properly.

This is a strange behavior, and my temporary solution is to mount the disk using *gparted* every time I boot. The problem now is to find out how to make gnome-disks able to mount the disk.

Differences between *gparted* and _gnome-disks-:

[image: differences between gparted and gnome disks]

The real size of *OS* is 400GB, not 429GB.

Comment: Can you still boot into Windows? Did you resize the NTFS partition using Windows `Disk Management` app, or `gparted`? Editing documents, or making any changes on the C: drive from Ubuntu is almost guaranteed to cause Windows problems. You should have a separate NTFS partition for sharing docs between OS's.

Comment: @heynnema I can still boot to Windows and everything's fine on Windows. I resized using a third party app on Windows because the Disk Management app didn't work (its another problem I saw on forums).

Comment: @heynnema I will think of having separate partition yes! But it's been 3 years I've used dual boot like this (accessing C from Ubuntu) and it was fine!

Comment: Show me a screenshot of `gparted`. Run `chkdsk /f c:` in Windows.

Comment: gparted: https://imgur.com/a/erULtZH

Comment: When I type the command `chkdsk /f c:` I have the following output:

`chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another process`

Do you think this can mean my whole problem is caused by a program constantly using the partition?

Comment: 1) edit your question and show me `sudo blkid`, and 2) when doing the chkdsk, it'll give that message, and it should tell you to reboot to actually do the chkdsk. Report back. Remember to start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema alright, thanks a lot for your help!

1) The output of sudo blkid is the same as I showed in my question, so you can check it just above

2) Here is the report of chkdsk: https://justpaste.it/2e6h6
Nothing seems wrong in the report. And I'm sorry it's in french, but I tried pasting it in Google Translate and the result is good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105475/discussion-between-clement-l-and-heynnema).

Comment: Your `chkdsk` was a mess. You may wish to run it again. As I mentioned in my very first comment, editing/changing files on your C: drive, from Ubuntu, is asking for trouble... and you have trouble. Temporarily comment out your mount in /etc/fstab, and replace it with: `UUID=01D5F7A77E62A210  /mnt/os ntfs-3g    defaults   0       0`, then `sudo mount -a`. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Alright your command `UUID=01D5F7A77E62A210 /mnt/os ntfs-3g defaults 0 0` worked! Let me try to mount on startup and it could be good!
Also I will definitely create a shared partition for my files as you said

Comment: @heynnema it works perfectly, big thanks!
It would be perfect if you could write an answer to the question explaining a bit what your edit changed on the boot options.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in earlier comments, mounting your Windows C: drive, and then modifying it from Ubuntu, is asking for Windows problems. And you have multiple Windows problems.

First, boot into Windows, and run `chkdsk /f c:` and reboot. You've done this already once, at my suggestion, and there were lots of errors. Run it again.

Second, if you wish to share files between Windows and Ubuntu, create a separate NTFS partition on your hard disk. Call it "Shared_Data" if you wish. Then it can be accessed from both OS's.

Third, try changing your `/etc/fstab`:

Change:

```
UUID=01D5F7A77E62A210 /mnt/os auto noatime,user,nls=utf8,windows_names,dmask=022,fmask=111,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

To:

```
UUID=01D5F7A77E62A210 /mnt/os ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

Then do a `sudo mount -a` or just reboot.

This forces the type to ntfs-3g instead of auto, and simplifies the options from that of the `Disks` application. You may need to further change "defaults" to **some** of the earlier options, if you have permissions problems accessing the data. But again, modifying your Windows C: partition can be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

If you could mount your disk in gparted, you could check how gparted mounts it in `/etc/mtab` and use that information to correct your `/etc/fstab` record.

Also, try to use the next command to identify your UUID:

```
sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,size,type,ro,label,uuid
```

I do not have windows partitions, but `cat /etc/fstab | grep home` shows:

```
UUID=248cea91-2ea8-4065-9039-0c5fcdb3fc98 /home ext4 defaults 0 0

$ sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,size,type,ro,label,uuid | grep home
[sudo] password for user: 
└─sdb1 /home                             232.9G part  0       248cea91-2ea8-4065-9039-0c5fcdb3fc98
```

As you can see, `/home` mount point has `sdb1` partition connected.

So its UUID in `/etc/fstab` could by replaced by `/dev/sdb1` as in my case. But using UUIDs is more reliable because of device name could change in case of new storage device connected before OS boot.

Comment: Here is the line from `/etc/mtab` about my _OS_ drive:

`/dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/os fuseblk rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0`

I tried to paste it in `/etc/fstab` and my PC wouldn't boot. I had to use maintenance mode to remove the line in order to boot again.

Comment: I thought it could contain your UUID which you have to replace with your UUID in `/etc/fstab`, but not the string as it is. Sorry for that. Have you tried that command to get your UUID? `sudo lsblk -o ...`?

Comment: No problem! I already have the UUID of the partition, you can see it in the output from the command `sudo blkid` I wrote in my answer. It's 01D5F7A77E62A210

Comment: @Gryu using the UUID in /etc/fstab is more reliable than using the /dev name.

Comment: @heynnema Ok. Thanks for clarification.